# Rspec on multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rspec

We used Rails and 1 database for both project's parts: back-office and API.
And rspec for API used default schema.rb with all tables.
Now we moved API's tables to another database and use establish_connection  in models to connect backoffice's database to retrieve necessary data.
How to organize rspec testing now if current schema.rb of API contains only 2 tables (for API) and don't know anything about backoffice's tables?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard to help you design your system when it's based on a brief verbal description. Also - we like to see that you've at least tried to have a go at solving this yourself before helping you. How about you show us the code you've tried (even if it's not working, even if it's just pseudo code)? along with some examples of what you mean, and what a working solution would look like.

Comment: Note: DO NOT ANSWER IN THE COMMENTS - code formatting is awful, and this information should be part of your original question. Instead, edit your question and add in all the information there. Use this as a good example of Stack Overflow questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask